# Testing AVPlayer sounds

Tags: ios, audio, xctest

I have a sound based app, and when i wrote a test case to test that the sound works

the sound does not play, when run in test case, and it does play when run in real app.

Why doesnt it work in the test case ?

In my SoundManager
i have a property called AVPlayer *audioPlayer

this is what i use to play the sound

```
-(void)play:(AVAudioPlayer *)player afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval )delay{
    if(self.audioPlayer){
        [self.audioPlayer stop];
    }
    self.audioPlayer = player;
    [self.audioPlayer setEnableRate:YES];
    [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

    [self.audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:0];
    [self.audioPlayer setVolume:0.03];
    [self.audioPlayer setRate:1.155f];
    [self.audioPlayer performSelector:@selector(play) withObject:nil afterDelay:delay];

}
```

Please to be VERY CLEAR: the sound DOES work in real app
I want to know why it DOESNT work on the TEST cases :

here is my test case:

```
-(void)testPlayAllSounds{

    Prefs *prefs = [[Prefs alloc]init];
    SoundManager *soundManager = [SoundManager initWithSoundSettingProvider:prefs];
    NSTimeInterval delay =3;
    NSTimeInterval interval = 3.0;
    NSError *error;
     AVPlayer   *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mp3"]  error:&error];
        if(!error){
            [soundManager play:player afterDelay:delay];
        }else{
            LogInfo(@"error playing sound");
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I meant this to be a comment but I guess I don't have enough reputation yet,

I would say that you need to think asynchronously for this test to succeed.
You either need some GCD semaphores, or include an asynchronous testing library and use that.

`initWithContents` might take time to complete, by then your tests are over.
You are adding a delay. That spins off other threads.

Answer (score 0):

Your `AVPlayer` is not retained by anything, and is being released when the `testPlayAllSounds` method returns. You'll need to assign it to an instance or static variable to make sure it sticks around long enough to start playing.

The other problem here is that your test method will just return straight away before your `SoundManager` has a chance to do anything, and it too will be released. If you want to do things this way you'll need to use `dispatch_group_wait()` or similar to make the test method wait until you're done.

I wouldn't recommend testing like this as it's error prone and slow, but it's hard to know what to recommend. I had a stab at mocking `AVPlayer` (and using DI to inject it into my own code) but I eventually gave up as I was using too much of its API surface (`AVPlayerItem` etc) and it was too complicated.

In general I hope future APIs from Apple are broken down more into small Swift protocols so DI and mocking are realistic options.

Answer (score 0):

Use async to wait the avplayer to complete or for an interval. Here is how to play media in XCTest:

```
- (void) testPlaySound_time_20_seconds {
      NSURL *fileUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: FILE_TO_PLAY];
      self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileUrl];
      //Expectation
      XCTestExpectation *expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"AVPlayer running!"];

    [self.avPlayer play];
    [self.avPlayer addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1)
    queue:NULL // main queue
    usingBlock:^(CMTime time)
      {
          UInt64 totalSeconds = (UInt64 )(time.value) / (UInt64)(time.timescale);
          NSLog(@"progress %llu", totalSeconds);
          if (totalSeconds == 20)
          {
              [expectation fulfill];
          }
    }];

    [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:500.0 handler:^(NSError *error) {
      if(error)
        {
            XCTFail(@"Expectation Failed with error: %@", error);
        }
    }];
}
```